HttpClient to docker query performance when using filters is dreadful - how to improve it?
I am running a chromadb 0.5.4 in a docker container with a database containing around 200k documents. Embeddings algorithm is the text-embedding-ada-002, which has 1536 dimensions. Wanting to make what would appear to be, relatively trivial query with a simple filter. All documents have a type_id, of [1, 2, 3]. Running the query without a filter has the results come back ~500ms, similar to running it with the PersistentClient locally. However when applying the filter
{ "$or": [ { "type_id": 1 }, { "type_id": 2}] }

or
{ "type_id": 3 }

Query performance bombs. And really bombs. The first query finishes in around 50 seconds, the second, in around 230 seconds. Both of these queries appear to run just fine locally, with around 400ms for each query.
Added more memory to the container, based on chroma's suggestions:
mem = no_docs * model_dimensions * 4

So the container runs with 3GB of memory; although the total is just over 1.1GB according to this calculation (1,228,800,000 bytes or better: 1,200,000 KB). Query performance still stinks, and the container is not using much of its allowed memory. CPU is not doing much, and adding additional cores did nothing for the performance.
Testing locally with our own container on a notebook, reducing the memory to 1GB did result in the query performance hitting around 19s for the first, but as soon as the memory was bumped back up to 3GB the container on the notebook started returning sub-second latencies.
What I have not done yet is use a model with fewer dimensions which is going to be the next thing to do.
Other things that I am going to do, and some of them are scraping the barrel a little bit:

Separate out the different typed documents into different databases to avoid using filters and just run two types of HttpClient, 'collection_1_2' and 'collection_3'
Run the chroma via the PersistentClient in the API, despite the warning not to do this in production. Performs a lot better than the docker server with the filtered queries.
Retrieve loads more documents and manually filter them. Instead of running a query for 10 docs for the various types, retrieve a 100, sort by distance, and then separate those out into types.

I would prefer not to do any of this (other than the embeddings dimensions reduction which just makes sense) and instead just make the relevant changes so the query finishes several orders of magnitude faster.
